# MySQL COUNT function not performing as I would like in multiple joined query

Tags: mysql, count, aggregate-functions

I have been altering a query for a while now, reading many posts on this wonderful site to get to where I am with this so far.  But, alas, now I am stuck :(

This query and relevant part of the database I have designed is similar to the youtube comment liking system.  Relevant tables and fields are:

USRS
usr_id int (PK)

COMMENTS
  comment_id int (PK)
  usr_id int (FK) references usrs(usr_id)
  topic_id int (FK) references topics(topic_id)
  descr varchar
  created varchar

COMMENT_LIKERS
  comment_id int (PK) (FK) references comments(comment_id)
  usr_id int (PK) (FK) references usrs(usr_id)
  liker tinyint

I want to be able to select all relevant data in one query. Aside from general data for each comment, I want to count all likes and dislikes for each comment.  The query I have thus far is counting the likes for ALL comments and not for each even though I have the LEFT JOIN with ON clause: comments.comment_id = comment_likers.comment_id.

I am learning MySql and PHP so go easy with me if I have done something silly.  I assure you I have looked all around for clues to the answer.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT comments.comment_id, comments.descr, comments.created, usrs.usr_name,
  COUNT(if(comment_likers.liker = 1, 1, null)),
  COUNT(if(comment_likers.liker = 0, 1, null)),
  comment_likers2.liker
FROM comments
INNER JOIN usrs ON ( comments.usr_id = usrs.usr_id )
LEFT JOIN comment_likers ON ( comments.comment_id = comment_likers.comment_id )
LEFT JOIN comment_likers AS comment_likers2 ON ( comments.comment_id = comment_likers.comment_id AND comment_likers.usr_id = $usrID )
WHERE comments.topic_id = $tpcID
GROUP BY comments.comment_id
ORDER BY comments.created DESC
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it is your problem, but I would put " AND comment_likers.usr_id = $usrID" in the where clause instead of the join.

Comment: I don't know if I am going mad here, having stared at this code for too long... but I know what you mean, I have switched over similar AND's in other queries to the WHERE clause with no apparent difference but I just tried doing so with this one and the query doesn't even work... no comments are found

Comment: I should have added this link in my comment, that I stumbled upon in my quest for answers in this project: http://techstumbler.blogspot.com/2008/04/mysql-join-with-count.html I will go to bed now and hope for answers and a fresh head tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT comments.comment_id, comments.descr, comments.created, usrs.usr_name, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment_likers WHERE comment_id=comments.comment_id AND liker=1)likes,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment_likers WHERE comment_id=comments.comment_id AND liker=0)dislikes
  liker
FROM comments
INNER JOIN usrs ON ( comments.usr_id = usrs.usr_id )
LEFT JOIN comment_likers  ON ( comments.comment_id = comment_likers.comment_id 
 AND comment_likers.usr_id = $usrID )
WHERE comments.topic_id=$tpcID
ORDER BY comments.created DESC;
```

A couple notes. I wasn't too sure what the second left join on comment_likers was supposed to accomplish (the one using $usrID). Are you only interested in likes from on a specific topic from a specific user?

Also, you might think about changing the schema for comments `created` to be a datetime instead of a varchar.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you so so much! I wondered about subqueries but did not have enough understanding of them to see how to implement them in my query, now I do!  As soon as I get the rep to vote I will vote this up! In answer to your first note, yes I was indeed also intending to get the likes/dislikes for each comment for the specific user browsing the page at the time.  And the created was a whoopsie on my part when typing here. It is indeed a datetime in my database. Again thank you!